# how do i install the postproessing and Get_Rendering Package for spyder in windows

Tags: spyder, post-processing, opensees

"No Module named openseespy.opensees.postprocessing.Get_Rendering found"
the above problem shows each time i try to run the task
"import openseespy.opensees.postprocessing.Get-Rendering"

I tried installing it in anacoonda prompt by typing 'pip install postprocessing'
but the following pops up
"ERROR:Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement postprocessing (from versions: none)"
"ERROR:No matching distribution found for postprocessing"

Comment: The [documentation](https://openseespydoc.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) that I found with a quick web search suggests that the install command is `pip install openseespy` and the [import statement](https://openseespydoc.readthedocs.io/en/stable/src/plotcmds.html) should be `import openseespy.postprocessing.Get_Rendering`. If you are using Anaconda you should [create a new environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) rather than install new packages into the base environment.